# scrset siempre me carga la misma imagen

Tags: html5

```
<img src="./18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg"
        srcset="./0.jpg 800w,./500x200.png 500w,./375px.png 375w"
        sizes="(min-width:501px) 800px,(min-width:800px) 500px,(min-width:900px) 375px" />
```

Siempre me carga la imagen de 800w aunque cambie el tamaño de la pantalla, las demas no cargan

Quiero que dependiendo de la media query se muestre una u otra imagen pero que no se muestre la misma siempre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que el orden de los factores, altera el producto.

En el atribuo `sizes`, tienes:

```
  (min-width:501px) 800px
, (min-width:800px) 500px
, (min-width:900px) 375px
```

La condición `(min-width:501px)` podemos traducirla a lenguaje natural así:

> cuando el ancho de la ventana gráfica es de 501 píxeles o más.

Y según la documentación de [diferentes tamaños de imágenes responsivas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#resolution_switching_different_sizes):

> Note: ... **The browser ignores everything after the first matching condition**, so be careful how you order the media conditions.

Que yo traduciría así:

> Nota: ... **El navegador ignora todo lo que está después de la primera coincidencia**, así que sé cuidadoso con el orden de las condiciones de los medios.

Lo que está pasando es que, para cualquier *viewport* de 501 pixels o más, se va a cumplir siempre la primera condición. Es decir, un *viewport* de 1200 pixels, va a cumplir la condición de tener 501 o más y por tanto la evaluación va detenerse allí y nunca va a llegar a evaluar la condición `min-width:900px`, que también cumpliría y parece ser que es la que tienes en mente que use.

Otro par de cosas con tu código:

1. No tienes un valor por defecto en el atributo `size`, cuando ninguna condición se cumple, se utiliza el valor por defecto. Este tamaño se pone al final, sin ninguna condición.
2. Entre más grande es el *viewport* utilizas un tamaño más pequeño de imagen, ¿estás seguro de querer hacer eso?

Tomando en cuenta estas cosas, puedes re-ordenar el atributo, ajustar para que entre más ancho el viewport, más grande la imagen y dar un valor por defecto, por ejemplo:

```
  (min-width:900px) 900px
, (min-width:800px) 800px
, (min-width:501px) 500px
, 375px
```

Mi ejemplo, es hipotético, claro que si dejaras los valores que yo pongo tendrías que ajustar el `srcset` también, pero lo normal es ajustar el `size` al `srcset` real que tienes.